# Transition from vh to 100% on hover not working

Tags: css

Is this possible at all without javascript?

Here is my example: http://codepen.io/tknz/pen/Nrdaew

I'm trying to make the image go to its auto height on hover.

HTML:

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="image-item" src="http://i.imgur.com/GIWdCVA.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}
.image-container .image-item {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  height: 20vw;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in all;
}
.image-container .image-item:hover {
  max-height: none;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.5s ease-out all;
}
```

Comment: No, this is not possible with CSS unless the image has a stated height. Essentially, you are trying to transition to `auto` which is not possible without Js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your CSS code to:

```
.image-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.image-container .image-item {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: all 2s ease-out; // I use 2s to easy see animation
}

.image-container .image-item:hover {
  max-height: 999px;
}
```

This code `max-height: 999px;`, `999px` value is hard code for max-height of your images (because use without JS).

It works fine: [Here](http://codepen.io/huychau/pen/xOgXNv)

Comment: Huh? The URL does work. And the transition definitely doesn't work...

Comment: See my updated answer :)

Comment: Yup that works. Although its not perfect for every scenario, Its good for me. I don't need it to go beyond the 800px width. Thanks!